# Find pairs of values in one set that aren't in another

Tags: r

I have two datasets:

actions:

```
user_id,action_id,action
123,900,start
123,901,stop
124,902,stop
```

history:

```
user_id,action_id,action
123,901,stop
124,902,stop
125,903,start
```

I want to find rows where user_id and action_id are in the actions dataset but not in any row in history data set. It would have to match both user_id AND action_id in a single row. I don't care about the action columns matching.

So the output would be:

```
user_id,action_id,action
123,900,start
```

Or it could be merging the missing rows from actions into history:

merged:

```
user_id,action_id,action
123,900,start
123,901,stop
124,902,stop
125,903,start
```

I'm just not finding the way to way to match multiple variables in an 'AND' like fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `anti_join` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

anti_join(actions, history, by = c("user_id", "action_id"))
```

Comment: `anti_join` will only find rows that are in the first set and not in the second. I haven't found one that will do a symmetric anti-join (i.e., finding all rows in only one of the two sets).

Answer (score 1):

**Data**

```
user_id <-c(123,123,124)
action_id <-c(900,901,902)
action<-c("start","stop","stop")
actions<-data.frame(user_id, action_id, action)

user_id <-c(123,124,125)
action_id <-c(901,902,903)
action<-c("stop","stop","start")
history<-data.frame(user_id, action_id, action)
```

**Paste and subset**

```
actions$m<-paste(actions$user_id, actions$action_id, sep='-')
history$m<-paste(history$user_id, history$action_id, sep='-')

subset(actions, !(m %in% history$m))
```